# How to save-to/read-from file the reply from a PyQt StandardButton

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qmessagebox

I am trying to save the "state" of an App built with PyQt; for example, if the App shows an info popup and asks *"Do you want to see this message next time?"*; I need to save the reply to a file, so next time the user opens the app, it reads the file and knows what to do. I wrote this code:

```
reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Warning', text, QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.Yes)
print (reply) # No:65536, Yes=16384 
with open('state.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(reply)
```

but I get this error *TypeError: write() argument must be str, not StandardButton*.
So how do I save the **reply** to file, in some way that I can later read from file and use in an `if` statement.

Comment: hi, try f.write(str(reply)), or check type of reply: type(reply)

Comment: I would recomment using the [`QSettings`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) class. It already provides functionality to save settings like this in your registry or in an ini-file depending on the [format](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#details) you are using. You can read more about the usage right [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#details). It should make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
    reply = QMessageBox.question(
        self, 
        'Warning', 
        'text', 
        QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, 
        QMessageBox.Yes
    )

    print (reply, type(reply))                   # No:65536, Yes=16384 

    if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
        value = "Yes"                            # or  value = "16384"
    else:
        value = "No"                             # or  value = "65536"

    with open('state.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(value)                           # !!!     value
```

Comment: Awesome. I implemented it with a dictionary ```msgWrite = {QMessageBox.Yes : "Yes", QMessageBox.No : "No"} # decrypt to write text to file```